I am trying to detect pulses from an inductive coil
I have a rotating flywheel with an inductive pickup and a magnet passing in front of it a couple of times per rotation. The signal looks like this for low speed inputs of the rotor:

Apologies for the lack of scale. Y is 50mV per division, and X is 0.5s per division. At higher rotation speeds, the pulse amplitude rapidly increases up to and beyond 1V positive and negative swing.
My goal is to detect the pulses by turning them into a 3v3 TTL pulse so they can be used by a microcontroller GPIO.
I found what I thought was a suitable comparator circuit:

The comparator circuit uses the anti-parallel Schottky diodes to limit the swing of the input voltage, as the input pulse varies in proportion to the speed of the rotor.
I simulated this circuit in LTspice, to reasonably good results. I used a sine wave source as a stand-in for the pulse signal. The simulation shows the following results:

Unfortunately, the circuit wired up IRL, just gives me a constant output high for the shown input signal.
I know there may be cheaper/easier/better/more standard ways to do this, but I would be interested to know why my approach has failed.
Thanks!

What does does the front end of your real circuit look like - not the simulation.

My answer here might be relevant: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/707333/convert-0-12v-ac-signal-to-3-3v-binary-pulses/707340#707340

@MOSFET I am not sure what you mean by the front end? It's just the inductive pickup. I have shown it's output, but I assume it is a low resistance coil? That is why I modeled it as low resistance voltage sources. This also makes me think that the application of a bias voltage, as in your linked example, might not go too well, but I might be mistaken.

What I mean is that in your LTSpice schematic, you have a convoluted model of a coil - three voltage sources and several resistors? Anyway, the biasing in my linked example is to get the operating point within the CM range of the comparator - you mentioned that the output is railed with changing input signals and this would be a reason; you're operating outside the CM range of the comparator (maybe).

The pickup coil needs a bias voltage (Vdd/2) and some hysteresis for the comparator wouldn't hurt either. Try something like this:


The LT1719 shown in the model, includes slightly negative input voltages; are you sure it needs bias?

@Roanoke: a second vote for a bias voltage. I will try to model that and see what it looks like, then try to modify my circuit.

The bias voltage is to avoid any CM voltage problems. Yes, the input voltage range of the LT1719 includes GND and one input is always at GND potential. According to note 2 in the datasheet, the output should be valid in this case and not stuck to the positive rail.
